# My tabs are locked/greyed out

Tags: c#, tabs, tabcontrol

For some reason the tabs inside of my tabControl item in Visual Studio are greyed out. It's not letting me switch from tab to tab and the items inside the tabs are greyed out aswell, so I can't click on anything.

I checked the tabControl settings and the individual tabPages settings and the Locked property is set to "FALSE" so it shouldn't be that.

Any idea what it could be?

Here's the designer.cs code of my tabControl:

```
        // tabControl1
        // 
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage1);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage2);
        this.tabControl1.Controls.Add(this.tabPage3);
        this.tabControl1.ImageList = this.imageList1;
        this.tabControl1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(12, 12);
        this.tabControl1.Name = "tabControl1";
        this.tabControl1.SelectedIndex = 0;
        this.tabControl1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(466, 218);
        this.tabControl1.TabIndex = 0;
        //// 
        // tabPage1
        // 
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.buttonStopUTUBE);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.buttonStartUTUBE);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.numericUpDown1);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.numericUpDownYouTubeRun);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.listBoxYoutube5);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.listBoxYoutube4);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.listBoxYoutube3);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label8);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.labelYouTubeRunsLeft);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label2);
        this.tabPage1.Controls.Add(this.label1);
        this.tabPage1.ImageIndex = 0;
        this.tabPage1.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 28);
        this.tabPage1.Name = "tabPage1";
        this.tabPage1.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(458, 186);
        this.tabPage1.TabIndex = 0;
        this.tabPage1.Text = "YouTube Video";
        this.tabPage1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // tabPage2
        // 
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.buttonSTOPWEBSITE);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.buttonSTARTWEBSITE);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.listBoxWebsites);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.richTextBox1);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.numericUpDownWEBSITE);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.label9);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.label5);
        this.tabPage2.Controls.Add(this.label3);
        this.tabPage2.ImageIndex = 1;
        this.tabPage2.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 28);
        this.tabPage2.Name = "tabPage2";
        this.tabPage2.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage2.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(458, 186);
        this.tabPage2.TabIndex = 1;
        this.tabPage2.Text = "Website";
        this.tabPage2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        // 
        // tabPage3
        // 
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.button1);
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.txtYPassword);
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.txtYUsername);
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.label12);
        this.tabPage3.Controls.Add(this.label7);
        this.tabPage3.ImageIndex = 2;
        this.tabPage3.Location = new System.Drawing.Point(4, 28);
        this.tabPage3.Name = "tabPage3";
        this.tabPage3.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.tabPage3.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(458, 186);
        this.tabPage3.TabIndex = 2;
        this.tabPage3.Text = "Settings";
        this.tabPage3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        //
```

Comment: It sounds like the Enabled property is set to false

Comment: can you please share the part of code in the designer.cs file related to your tab control? for e.g. if your form is called Form1, then go to the file named Form1.designer.cs and for e.g. if your tab is called tab1 find the block of code with a comment on top showing tab1 and copy this code block into your question.

Comment: @Peter4499 Nope, Enabled on tabControl is set to True

Comment: @user1017524 and the tabs?

Comment: @Bishoy Just added it

Comment: Unless I'm looking in the wrong spot, the individual tabPages properties don't have a section for Enabled. It only has it for Locked. @Peter4499

Comment: Can I ask you as well to add the code blocks for all the three tab pages?
I cannot see anything wrong so far.
Do you have any code that access the tab properties in your form constructor or on form load?

Comment: @user1017524 You're right, my bad.

Comment: @Bishoy Done. Just added it.

Comment: Just to clarify - is this happening when you run the application, or are you experiencing problems at design stage in Visual Studio itself?

Comment: Only when I run the program @Übercoder

Comment: Is the form (or other container) that contains `tabControl1` enabled?

Comment: BINGO! WOW... I checked ALL the forms except the Form1 one. Thank you! @Übercoder